# PHP form not appearing

Tags: php, html

I cant seem to get the form to appear when i set the button type to submit it will appeared, but when the button is button i cant get the form out. I have  to make the code work with button type button.

```
        <script type ="text/javascript">
            function submitData() {

                var input = document.getElementById('objectname').value;
                document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML = "";
                if (input === "") {
                    document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'> You need to enter the object field</span>";
                }

                var option1 = document.getElementById('metal');
                var option2 = document.getElementById('wood');
                var option3 = document.getElementById('liquid');
                var option4 = document.getElementById('plant');
                var option5 = document.getElementById('animal');
                var option6 = document.getElementById('human');
                var option7 = document.getElementById('others');
                document.getElementById("optionerror").innerHTML = "";
                if (option1.checked === false && option2.checked === false && option3.checked === false && option4.checked === false
                        && option5.checked === false && option6.checked === false && option7.checked === false) {
                    document.getElementById("optionerror").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'> You need to select an object type</span>";
                }
                if (!(input === "") && (!(option1.checked === false) || !(option2.checked === false))) {
                    document.getElementById('myform').submit();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class ="input-group">
            <h1 class ="header">Object Classification</h1>
        </div>
        <form id="myform"  action="submit.php" method='get' target="hiddenframe">
            <dev class="input-group">
                <label>Object: </label>                 
                <input type="text" name="object" id="objectname">
                <span id="nameerror"></span>
            </dev>
            <p/>
            <dev class="input-group">
                <label >Type: </label>
                <input type="radio" name="option" value="metal" id="metal"/> Metal
                <input type="radio" name="option" value="wood" id="wood"/> Wood
                <input type="radio" name="option" value="liquid" id="liquid"/> Liquid
                <input type="radio" name="option" value="plant" id="plant"/> Plant
                <input type="radio" name="option" value="animal" id="animal"/> Animal
                <input type="radio" name="option" value="human" id="human"/> Human
                <input type="radio" name="option" value="others" id="others"/> Others
                <span  id="optionerror"></span>
            </dev>
            <p/>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="submitData();" ><br/> 
        </form>
        <div>
            <iframe width="500" height="500" style="border:none" name="hiddenframe"></iframe>            
        </div>
```

I have to transfer the data to server.php. When i set the button type to submit i can get this form to show. But when i set the button type to button, i cant get it to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to change the input to a button, use the following (note: the `<button>` element instead of `<input>`):

```
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

Then to submit your form you can do either:

1. As you were already doing, use your onclick in the button to call the js function, e.g. `<button type="submit" name="submit"  onclick="submitData();">Submit</button>` *or*
2. the standard way to submit a form is to use `onsubmit` in the `form` element and use the javascript function just for validation, like this:

   [... your form fields here... ]

   ```
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
   ```

If you use `onsubmit`, then your validation function should return `true` if everything is good to be submitted, or `false` otherwise so the form will prevent the submission from happening. The form itself will do the rest!

```
 function submitData() {
     // your validation checks here...

     if (!(input === "") && (!(option1.checked === false) || !(option2.checked === false))) {
          return true;    // no errors so return true to the form so it knows its ok to continue.
     }
    // if there were errors, return false so that the form knows not to submit
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to solve this issue but here is one:

You can keep the button type as "submit" but attach CSS to it:

CSS (just an example...you can use any other CSS):

```
.button{ padding:9px; font-size: 16px; background:#00912a; border:1px solid #037223; color:#fff !important;}
.button:hover{ background:#fff; border:1px solid #037223; color:#037223 !important;}
```

Code:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="submitData();" ><br/>
```